# UDP Client shows 'UDP Connected' while no UDP Server running on localhost

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

What is wrong with the following function ??

It should throw an error as I have no UDP server running on localhost.

```
int openUdpSocket(int port) {


    int sock,sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    struct hostent *host;
    host= (struct hostent *) gethostbyname((char *)"127.0.0.1"); 

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
      perror("socket");
      exit(1);
    }   

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);

    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
```

Now the Following part causing trouble : -

```
   int error = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

   if(error < 0){ 
      printf("Connection error\n");
      exit(-1);
   }   

   if (verbose) 
     printf("UDP connected\n");

return sock;
```

}

Output:

```
    udit@mylaptop:~/Desktop/benchmark$ ./a.out 
    UDP connected
```

Note that I have created a similar function for `TCP` and the same thing is working fine with TCP that means when no TCP Server running it shows `connection error` and when TCP Server running then `TCP Connected`

The UDP Client mentioned above needs to receive response in form of some status codes in future. SO, Do I need to use bind() function here ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to lookup what `connect()` does for a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket. It doesn't imply the existence of a peer. It only establishes an inbound and outbound IP address filter. See [*man 2 connect*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect).

Comment: then how to check the existence of a peer with udp .. can you suggest. I mean how can you confirm whether there is connection b/w server and client ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection. A peer can come and go without you knowing any more about it than the receipt of datagrams, or its cessation.

Comment: What you can do is have your client periodically send a packet to the server, and have the server respond by sending a packet back to the client.  Then in your client program, you can consider yourself "connected" iff you've received any packets from the server within the last (so many) seconds.  (It's not really a connection of course, but as far as the user is concerned it's the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

for UDP communication you need to use Sendto and Receivefrom functions,
bind and connect are not required for UDP communication.
try to search about this two functions and use them. :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'UDP connection'.

Comment: there is.
connection-less is used for UDP.
so we don't require bind and accept we just need to send packets
using sendto.

Comment: A connectionless connection is a contradiction in terms.